# Как менять текст при клике на пункт в dropdown списке?

Tags: javascript

Логика такая, при клике на пункт списка, например "Уфа" этот текст оказывался на месте текущего, а текущий в списке.

```js
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropdown-toggle')) {
    let dropdownMenu = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu');

    for (let i = 0; i < dropdownMenu.length; i++) {
      let openDropdown = dropdownMenu[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
};

const dropdownToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');

dropdownToggle.forEach(function(item) {
  item.onclick = function() {
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show')
  };
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-toggle {background: orange;}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-toggle">Москва</div>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item">Санкт-Петербург</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">Уфа</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему бы не использовать option > select в таком случае? что бы не писать лишний js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 
    if(!e.target.matches('.dropdown-toggle')){
       const dropdownMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu');

        dropdownMenus.forEach((menu) => {
            if (menu.classList.contains('show')){
                menu.classList.remove('show');
           }
        });
    }

});

const dropdownToggle = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle');

dropdownToggle.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('show')
    });
});

const dropdownItems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-item');

dropdownItems.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            let self = e.target;
            let toggle = self.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-toggle');
            const toggleText = toggle.innerText;
            toggle.innerText = self.innerText;
            self.innerText = toggleText;
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-toggle {background: orange;}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-toggle">Москва</div>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-item">Санкт-Петербург</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item">Уфа</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ещё вариант

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.list');

list.addEventListener('click', showSublist);

function showSublist({
  target
}) {
  if (target.classList.contains('list__item__heading')) {
    var sublist = target.nextElementSibling;

    sublist.classList.toggle('hidden');
    sublist.addEventListener('click', changeCity);
  }
}

function changeCity({
  target
}) {
  if (target.classList.contains('sublist__item')) {
    var tmp = target.innerText;
    var heading = target.parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild;

    target.innerText = heading.innerText;
    heading.innerText = tmp;
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <h4 class="list__item__heading">Москва</h4>
    <ul class="sublist hidden">
      <li class="sublist__item">Астрахань</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">Уфа</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">Владивосток</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="list__item">
    <h4 class="list__item__heading">Минск</h4>
    <ul class="sublist hidden">
      <li class="sublist__item">Могилев</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">Брест</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">Гродно</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```